# How to sort a text file containing integers in Spark - Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark programming, I have a data file named "test1.in" which contains random numbers in following way -

```
123
34
1
45
65
```

I want to sort these numbers using spark and write the output to a new file. Here is my code so far -

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SortingApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val data = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/test1.in")
val d1 = data.map(_.sorted)
d1.foreach(println _)
```

The result is not what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call:

```
data.map(_.sorted)
```

You map each record (which is a String) into it's "sorted" version, which means the String is being converted into a Sequence of `chars` and these chars are sorted.

What you need to do is **NOT** to use `map` which applies your function to *each record separately* (hence it can't sort the records), but use `RDD.sortBy`:

```
data.map(_.toInt).sortBy(t => t)
```

The `t => t` is the identity function returning the input as-as, which can be replaced with Scala's built-in generic implementation:

```
data.map(_.toInt).sortBy(identity)
```

Or, the shortest version:

```
input.sortBy(_.toInt)
```

(which would return a result of type `RDD[String]`)

Answer (score 0):

Use below line to convert text file data into `Int` then sort it:

```
val d1 = data.map(_.toInt).sorted
```